# Why @ExceptionHandler annotated methods are protected?

Tags: java, spring, access-modifiers, exceptionhandler

Although not explicitly specified in @ExceptionHandler's official documentation, almost in all the examples on web, methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler are protected. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Why should any code use such a class directly? Spring takes care to register the exception handler. That's all there is to do.

Comment: I wonder if there used to a class you would need to extend before `@ExceptionHandler` annotation came along

Comment: @LutzHorn not should but might. So can we say that's more to force cleaner design?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong this is because the methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler annotation are only active for that particular Controller, not globally for the entire application thus making them protected.

Comment: Can it be the opposite? I mean the method should be public when that annotation is used at Controller level. @ControllerAdvice implementations are almost always protected.

Comment: That being said, we can work around even without making them public all we have to do is having all Controllers extend a Base Controller class.